# jQuery + jQuery Mobile = Calling handlers two times?

Tags: jquery

I inserted jQuery (1.8.2) and jQuery mobile (1.1.1) on my web application.
Now, if I create this simple handler :

```
$('.pulsante-menu').click(function () {
    console.log("ooo");
});
```

and I click the link, I see that console message twice! How can I fix it?

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/fBjgu/9/) is my code!

Comment: You don't have an element of class `.pulsante-menu` inside another element that has `.pulsante-menu` do you? If so, the event should fire twice when you click the inner element. To get it to only fire once, add an event object as an argument to the event handler and then use its `.stopPropagation()` method to stop the event from bubbling up to the other `.pulsante-menu` element.

Comment: Added a working example! Check the console :O

Comment: @UselessCode: it is not my case! Check the example...

Comment: The link to other code wasn't there when I posted that comment, I couldn't check the example and had no way of telling what your markup looked like. Event bubbling is the most common thing that causes the symptom you were describing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move your script in your `<head>` element or in a separate JavaScript file. Or try using [pageinit](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/api/events.html). Reason why it does this is explained [in this post on jQuery.com](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-jquerymobile-document-ready-called-twice).

Answer (score 0):

You have the handler defined twice in your fiddle, once in the JS section and once in a script tag in the HTML section. Remove one of them and it should work.

Check my updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TVUNZ/).

HTML:

```
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
  <script src="http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/js/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <a href="#" class="prova">Link</a>
</body>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('.prova').click(function () {
    console.log("ooo");
    return false; // stopPropagation and preventDefault
});
```

​

Comment: Well, that was just a mine error on copy and paste! Try this http://jsfiddle.net/fBjgu/9/

Comment: Also, your example jquery mobile, which cause problems!

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this.

```
$('.pulsante-menu').click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    console.log("ooo");
});
```

Comment: this make no sense! Why it is displayed twice?